# Rename Bibliography while using APA7 package

Tags: biblatex, apa7

Minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass[stu]{apa7}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa,
sortcites=true,
sorting=nyt,
]{biblatex}
\shorttitle{Hello}

\addbibresource{annot.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={New Reference Title}]{}

\end{document}
```

The title of "References" does not change to the new title. I suspect the problem with `apa7` package. When changing the document class to `article`, the title changes.

Question: how to change the bibliography title?

What I tried: set `\printbibliography[heading=none]` then manually add `\section{new title}`. But I want to know the proper way to rename it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Following https://github.com/dan-weiss/apa7-latex-cls-source/issues/20, version 2.08 and above of `apa7.cls` no longer hard code the bibliography title and make it possible to use the `title` argument to `\printbibliography`.

---

### Old answer

`apa7.cls` hard-codes the bibliography heading as follows

```
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}{%  the user has loaded biblatex
    \@ifundefined{def@man}{%
      \defbibheading{bibliography}{\section*{\normalfont\textbf\refname}}%
    }{%
      \defbibheading{bibliography}{\clearpage\section*{\normalfont\textbf\refname}}%
    }
  }{}
}
```

while something like

```
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}{%  the user has loaded biblatex
    \@ifundefined{def@man}{%
      \defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{\section*{\normalfont\textbf{#1}}}%
    }{%
      \defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{\clearpage\section*{\normalfont\textbf{#1}}}%
    }
  }{}
}
```

might have been slightly more flexible as it would have allowed for the `title` option of `\printbibliography` to work properly.

You can counter the definition `apa7.cls` makes as follows (we need to use `\AtBeginDocument` to come in with our definition after `apa7.cls`' change takes effect), but you may want to notify the author of `apa7.cls` about this. Maybe they would like to change things so that the `title` option becomes usable again.

```
\documentclass[stu, american]{apa7}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=apa,
]{biblatex}
\shorttitle{Hello}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{\clearpage\section*{\normalfont\textbf{#1}}}%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
lorem
\printbibliography[title={New Reference Title}]
\end{document}
```

[image: New Reference Title]

Comment: Thank you so much. I have opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/dan-weiss/apa7-latex-cls-source/issues/20

Answer (score 1):

The feature to change the title of the References section has been added in apa7.cls version 2.08

```latex
\printbibliography[title={New Reference Title}]{}
```

Will now work in an apa7 document without modifications.